# How to populate Excel spreadsheet from another spreadsheet by Filename lookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

First of all, I really don't have advanced knowledge of working with Excel formulas. So please help me achieve the desired functionality.

I have two spreadsheets named [a.xlsx](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/37127032/a.xlsx) and [b.xlsx](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/37127032/b.xlsx). I want that when I enter name of spreadsheet `a.xlsx` in `b.xlsx` in a `blue highlighted cell` it will automatically populate the respective columns (not all columns, so column needs to be mapped accordingly) from first file to another.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated. Thanks.

*Edited*

Those who are also facing this problem try to follow [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799455/what-is-wrong-with-this-excel-formula/7799547) thread to know the solution.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro to get started? People appreciate it if you show you have made some effort.

Comment: Acually i am new in excel formulas, this was the task assigned to me by one of my employer i can't refuse him. so now i am stuck :( just formula is required which will do file lookup then respective columns lookup. Please Help!

Comment: I haven't looked at your files, but it sounds like you could use something along the lines of an INDIRECT() formula creating a cell reference from the file name in the blue highlighted cell.  And maybe wrap the whole formula in an IFERROR(..., "") to prevent showing error messages when no file name is entered.

Comment: It isnt clear to me what you want. Do you have a sample you could show us? Or an example you provide online?

Comment: @brettdj `a.xlsx` and `b.xlsx` has url link. Please clik on them to download excel fies. Waiting for your response. Thanks

Comment: Aamir, will both files be open at the the same time. Or if a.xlsx is closed, where should b.xlsx look to retrieve the data?

Comment: Both files may be open at the same time. the `b.xlsx` need to look for the file in the same directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is wrong with this Excel Formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799455/what-is-wrong-with-this-excel-formula)

Answer (score 1):

Let

- A1 contain the filename (e.g. "Source.xls")
- A2 contain the sheet name (e.g. "Sheet1")
- A3 contain a cell reference (e.g. "A3")

paste into A4 the following formula

```
="'[" & A1 & "]" & A2 & "'!" & A3
```

to calculate a valid external reference, then, in any cell you desire, enter formula

```
=INDIRECT(A4)
```

**disadvantage:** source file must be open, otherwise you get a #REF error.

Alternatively you can use VBA to open/read/close another file ... not complicated either but as this question is tagged "formula" I won't elaborate on that now.

Comment: Thanks for response, but my problem is solved. I have edited my question and added a link to the solution. Thanks again.